# Minimizing overhead for large trees in java

Tags: java, tree, overhead, octree, bigdata

I need to implement a large octree in Java.  The tree will be very large so I will need to use a paging mechanism and split the tree into many small files for long-term storage.

My concern is that Java objects have a very high space overhead.  If I were using C, I would be able to store the 8 reference pointers and any other data with only a byte or so of overhead to store the node type.

Is there any way that I can approach this level of overhead in Java?

I would be tempted to just use a single byte array per file.  I could then use offsets in place of pointers (this is how I plan on storing the files).  However, even when limiting the max file size, that would easily leave me with arrays too large to fit in contiguous memory, particularly if that memory becomes heavily fragmented.  This would also lead to large time overheads for adding new nodes as the entire space would need to be reallocated.  A ByteBuffer might resolve the first problem (I am not entirely sure of this), however it would not solve the second, as the size of a ByteBuffer is static.

For the moment I will just stick to using node objects.  If anyone knows a more space efficient solution with a low time cost, please let me know.

Comment: To clarify, is the memory concern focused around a large number of node or a large size of an individual node?  Whichever is the case, can you please elaborate?

Comment: My concern is the size of the individual nodes.  The large number of nodes is somewhat unavoidable due to the application.  Since I will want to keep as many nodes in memory as possible in order to reduce execution time, I would like to reduce the size of the nodes by as much as possible.